# How to go about proving a result for this matrix equation involving a time-dependent rotation matrix?

Tags: matrices, functions, vectors, matrix-equations, rotations

Consider the ${3 \times 3}$ matrix $M$ whose entries consist of functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ given by

$M_{ij} =
\begin{cases}
\cos^2\big(\frac{1}{2}\phi\big)+\sin^2\big(\frac{1}{2}\phi\big)\big(2(N_i)(N_i)-1\big), & \text{if $i=j$} \\
2(N_i)(N_j)\sin^2\big(\frac{1}{2}\phi\big)+\epsilon_{ijk}(N_k)\sin(\phi), & \text{if $i \neq j$}
\end{cases}$

where  $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is the Levi-Cevita symbol with $\epsilon_{123}=1$ and $\phi$, $N_1$, $N_2$, and $N_3$ are class $C^3$ differentiable functions such that $N_1(x)^2+N_2(x)^2+N_3(x)^2=1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Let $t \in \mathbb{R}$ be fixed and denote by $Q \in M_{3 \times 3}(\mathbb{R})$ the matrix defined by evaluating each entry of $M$ at $t$. Also, denote by $Q',Q'' \in M_{3 \times 3}(\mathbb{R})$ the matrices defined by the entrywise first and second derivatives, respectively, of $M$ at $t$.

Now let $x,y,z \in M_{3 \times 1}(\mathbb{R})$ be any three column vectors. Consider the following matrix equation:

$Q''Q^Tx+2Q'y-Qz=0_{3 \times 1}$

How should I go about proving that the above equation implies $Q'=0_{3 \times 3}$ and, consequently, $z=0_{3 \times 1}$? Or does there exist a counterexample that I have yet to think of? It is probably important to note that $Q$ is a clockwise rotation matrix regardless of the value of $t$.

Comment: For $3 \times 3$ rotation matrices, "clockwise" doesn't make sense without a chosen axis, for if $M$ rotates clockwise by $\theta$ about $v$, then it rotates counterclockwise by $\theta$ about $-v$.

Comment: The axis is given by the vector $(N_1(x),N_2(x),N_3(x))$ for some fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: In which case it's also given by $(-N_1(x), -N_2(x), -N_3(x))$, since an axis for a rotation is simply an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$. Even so, as my example shows, the clockwise-ness is irrelevant.

Comment: The clockwise-ness is indeed relevant, and it is induced by the right-hand rule about the axis $(N_1(x),N_2(x),N_3(x))$.

Comment: I meant "irrelevant" in the sense that it doesn't seem to help with your claim being true/false. It may matter to you for some other reason, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your claim is false. Let me simplify a little by letting
$$
X = Q^T x\\
Z = Qz
$$
and noting that by choosing $x$ and $z$ appropriately, we can make $X$ and $Z$ have any value we want. So now your challenge is to show that in 
$$
Q''X + Q'y + Z = 0
$$
the only possibility is that $Q' = 0$ and $Z = 0$. But that's not true.

For instance, no matter what value $Q'$ has, we can pick $X = 0$, and choose any nonzero $y$, and then the equation becomes 
$$
Q' y + Z = 0
$$
which is easily solved by picking $Z = -Q' y$.

(To get $z$, we write $z = Q^{-1}Z = Q^t Z$; to get $x$, we write $x = QX$.)

Let me get even more explicit: Pick $N_1(x)= N_2(x) = 0$ and $N_3(x) = 1$ for all $x$; let $\phi(t) = t$. Then, letting $c$ and $s$ denote the since and cosine of $t$, we have something like
$$
M 
= \pmatrix{c & s & 0 \\
-s & c & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1}
$$
(where I might have the signs on the $s$ swapped). 
So 
$$
M' 
= \pmatrix{-s & c & 0 \\
-c & -s & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0}
$$
and 
$$
M'' 
= \pmatrix{-c & -s & 0 \\
s & -c & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0}
$$
Picking $t = \pi/2$, we have $s = 1$ and $c = 0$, so 
$$
Q = 
= \pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1}\\
Q'  
= \pmatrix{-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0}\\
Q''  
= \pmatrix{0 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0}
$$
Note in particular that $Q'$ is **not** zero .

Now pick $x = 0, y = \pmatrix{0 \\ 1 \\ 0};$ the equation you've highlighted then reads
$$
 \pmatrix{0 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0}
\pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1}^T \pmatrix{0\\0\\0}  + 2 \pmatrix{-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0} \pmatrix{0 \\ 1 \\ 0} - 
\pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1}\pmatrix{z_1 \\ z_2 \\ z_3} = \pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ 0}.
$$

The first term is evidently zero; the second is $\pmatrix{0 \\ -2 \\ 0}$, and by picking $z$ to be \pmatrix{2 \ 0 \ 0}, we get equality, without $z$ being the zero vector.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed response